# How to convert PDF to Image without generating a file

Tags: ghostscript

Based on the Code [How-To-Convert-PDF-to-Image-Using-Ghostscript-API](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32274/How-To-Convert-PDF-to-Image-Using-Ghostscript-)

I trying to figure out how to get a image foreach page without creating the files

To get an image foreach Page i setted `OutputToMultipleFile = true`.

Then i went step for step through his code but i wasn't able to find the part where the files get created.


So i want to know what i need to change in this code?
or anything else which helps to achieve this

### EDIT

here my current parameters:

```
args[0] =
args[1] =-dNOPAUSE 
args[2] =-dBATCH 
args[3] =-dSAFER 
args[4] =-sDEVICE=pnggray 
args[5] =-r130 
args[6] =-sOutputFile="C:\Scannen1.PDF%d.png" 
args[7] ="C:\Scannen1.PDF"
```

Comment: if you already know how to do a job with generating a file, then questions are: what is a problem to do it in this way and why you must do it without generating a file?

Comment: @Sinatr because i doesn't need the file  and AFAIK my app doesn't get any write permissions so i have to do it over the memory

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a device which doesn't write to file, *all* the image format devices write their output to file. You could use the display device which will return you a bitmap in memory as a template and write your own device, or you can modify one of the existing devices.

Modifying an existing device is a task for a developer and while not excessively difficult is not trivial either.

In any event, you aren't going to get what you want by fiddling with command line switches. Like Sinatr I'm puzzled by what you can usefully do with Ghostscript which doesn't involve writing to file.

Oh, one other possibility is to load the nulldevice, which is done in PostScript and is simply a bit bucket.

Comment: do you know an sample for your device suggestion

Comment: It depends what exactly you want to do. The display device would seem a reasonable place to start if you want a bitmap in memory.

Comment: The user will give my app an pdf where each Page will be an Picture and now i need to get each Image separate to some modifications and save it afterwards in my DataBase

Comment: This sounds like a sub-optimal way to proceed, why not have the user send you the 'Picture' instead ? Or an archive format containing the original images. Embedding it in a PDF file will likely change the formatting, may change the colour space, might affect any transparency, etc. Rendering the PDF file will do all of the above, as well as potentially changing the resolution of the image. If you really must proceed this way, then don't render the PDF at all, use something like pdftk to extract the images without further processing them.

Comment: they will scanne multiple checklists `1 to undefine` and the Scanner is able to output that as an PDF file so they only need to presend me this file it's more easyer for my users after that i scann the Image (now in gray) in my app identifie the checkboxes and the bare-code (costumer) and and present the user an UI where he can double check (foreach image) the information's i found edit it and save it to the database. So i will still get a PDF or a bulk of Images (but i'm sure they are to braindead to give me the Images)

Comment: I'd still suggest that, rather than rendering the PDF, you simply extract the images directly from the PDF file, iTextSharp might help you here, there may be other solutions. If you really want to go down the road of using Ghostscript, then I suggest you look at the display device, especially since you are working on Windows. The Windows display device calls back to the main application to do the display. Look in dwmain.c, the 'display_page' routine. You can then look in dwimg.c to see how the bitmap is displayed.